# How can i filter a models field in django?

Tags: django, django-models, filtering

im quite new in backend development so i got a basic question.

I've three different models one named Campaigns;

```
class Campaigns(models.Model):
   
   channel = models.ForeignKey(Channels, blank=False, verbose_name="Channel Name", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   campaign_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, verbose_name="Campaign Name")
```

Second one is;

```
class CampaignDetails(models.Model):
   channel = models.ForeignKey(Channels, blank=False, null=True, verbose_name="Channel Name", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.ForeignKey(Campaigns, blank=False, null=True, verbose_name="Campaign", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And the last one is;

```
Class Channels(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="Tv Channel")
```

I want to filter name in CampaignDetails by channel. Like if i choose channel 1 i want to filter name by campaign names that under that channel. How can i manage that?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: So your CampaignDetails already have relation to channel, is there any reason for Campaign to have relation to channel as well?

Comment: My thought was all campaigns can assigned different channels, that's why i related them

Comment: Yes, I get that, however, CampaignDetails "already" have relation to channel for your Campaign. So is there any other reason for Campaign to have the relation too?

Comment: I got your point, i wanted to use channel relation for filtering campaigns by channel which i failed to manage.
That's why i'm asking "how can i filter campaigndetails by channel"

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question. so I can give you some decision.For example            You can filter it :

```html
channel=Channel.objects.get(pk=1)
channel.campaigndetails_set.all() #or channel.campaigndetails_set.filter(name='your name')
```

I'm not sure about the answer, but i think it will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
champaigns = Campaigns.objects.filter(chanel=Channels.objects.get(name="Chanel name"))
for i in champaigns:
     print(i.channel)
```

same goes for the other models you can do that by other methods too however you find it easy

in template

```
{%for i in champaigns%}
{{i.channel}}
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: This might work in view but i want to filter it admin panel. It's like when i chose channel A, i want to see which campaigns are added in channel A. I want to filter it in model

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have 2 channels. But if you want to filter it by channel

```
campaign_details = CampaignDetails.objects.filter(channel__name="insert_channel_name_here")
```

Well if you want to clean up. Remove channel from campaign details, and change the name of the foreign key "name" to campaign

```
campaign_details = CampaignDetails.objects.filter(campaign__channel__name="insert_channel_name_here")
```